# Register Design in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I'm having some troubles in designing a 1-bit and 32-bit register in VHDL. Main inputs of the register include clock (clk), clear (clr), load/enable(ld) signals and an n-bit data (d).
The n-bit output is denoted by (q). So far I believe to have made a 1-bit register, here is my code:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.std_logic_arith.ALL;
USE ieee.std_logic_unsigned.ALL;
ENTITY register32 IS
PORT(
d : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0); -- input.
ld : IN STD_LOGIC; -- load/enable.
clr : IN STD_LOGIC; -- async. clear.
clk : IN STD_LOGIC; -- clock.
q : OUT STD_LOGIC; -- output.
END register32;
ARCHITECTURE description OF register32 IS

BEGIN

 process(clk, clr, ld)
   begin
      if clr = '1' then 
         q <= '0';
      elsif d = '1' and ld = 1 and clk'event and clk='1' then
         q <= '1';
      elsif d = '0' and ld = 1 and clk'event and clk='1' then
         q <= '0';
      else
         q <= '0';
      end if;
   end process;
END description;
```

If this is correct for a 1-bit register, how would I make it into a 32 bit one. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 26):

So let's first look at some issues in your code:

- You have a 32 bit input, and 1 bit output, but presumably that's just an accident.
- When you're not reseting the register, and we're not on the rising_edge, you unconditionally set the output to `'0'`. That isn't modeling a register, so let's remove that.
- We can also simplify your internal logic by just assigning `d` to `q` at the appropriate time. (This makes the 32-bit logic much simpler as well).
- We can write `clk'event and clk='1'` as just `rising_edge(clk)`.
- There are some small syntax issues in your port declaration. Note that the last member does not end in a semicolon, and the port declaration itself ends in a `);`

So, this causes us to have for a one bit register:

```
ENTITY register1 IS PORT(
    d   : IN STD_LOGIC;
    ld  : IN STD_LOGIC; -- load/enable.
    clr : IN STD_LOGIC; -- async. clear.
    clk : IN STD_LOGIC; -- clock.
    q   : OUT STD_LOGIC -- output.
);
END register1;

ARCHITECTURE description OF register1 IS

BEGIN
    process(clk, clr)
    begin
        if clr = '1' then
            q <= '0';
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            if ld = '1' then
                q <= d;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
END description;
```

And if we wanted to extend this to 32 bits:

```
ENTITY register32 IS PORT(
    d   : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
    ld  : IN STD_LOGIC; -- load/enable.
    clr : IN STD_LOGIC; -- async. clear.
    clk : IN STD_LOGIC; -- clock.
    q   : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0) -- output
);
END register32;

ARCHITECTURE description OF register32 IS

BEGIN
    process(clk, clr)
    begin
        if clr = '1' then
            q <= x"00000000";
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            if ld = '1' then
                q <= d;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
END description;
```